# How to run parallel execution with ant

Tags: python-2.7, ant

I did parallel execution using junit with ant. I need to parallel run for my tests in Python. Can we use ant for this? If yes, how?
If not , what is the way to achieve parallel run of tests in Python ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works

```
    class myThread (threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
            self.threadID = threadID
            self.name = name
            self.counter = counter
        def run(self):
            print "Starting " + self.name
            if (self.name=="Android"):
                 print self.name

            elif (self.name=="ios") : 
                print self.name

            else:
                print self.name

            print "Exiting " + self.name

//Creating new Threads
thread1 = myThread(1, "Android", 1)
thread2 = myThread(2, "ios", 2)
thread3 = myThread(3,"windowsphone",3)

//Start new Threads
thread2.start()
thread1.start()
thread3.start()
```